# mocha: how to call async functions in after()?

Tags: mocha.js, sails.js

I'm writing a test that verifies the creation of models and then after the describe, it releases all the resources.

My problem is that 'done()' is called more than once, it is obvious why, but how can I implement such functionality and call done only once? both functions are async!

The test structure and async calls:

```
describe('create models', function() {
     it('...', function(done) {...});
});
after(function(done) {
         dbDestroyCenter('param1','param2')(done);
         dbDestroyCenter('param1','param2')(done);
});
```

The delete function:

```
function dbDestroyCenter(centerState, centerName) {
    return function (done) {
        State.findOne({ name: centerState }).exec(function (err, state) {

            if (err) return done(err);
            expect(state).not.to.be.an('undefined');

            Center.destroy({ state: state.id, name: centerName }).exec(function(err) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                return done();
            });
        });
    };
}
```

One possibility is to use async.parallel from https://github.com/caolan/async, but I am not sure Mocha doesn't provide solution for this. **Any ideas?**

Comment: Nope, this is what things like `async` were designed for.  Mocha doesn't replicate that functionality (it doesn't need to).  You could also just wrap the second `dbDestroyCenter` call in a function and make *that* function the callback to the first `dbDestroyCenter` instead of done, but using `async` is more efficient (and prettier).

Answer (score 2):

Pass your own callback to the function returned by your `dbDestroyCenter` function and keep a count. Once you its been called the number of times you expect, you're done and can call `done`.

```
after(function(done) {
    // Initialize to the number of things to destroy.
    var to_destroy = 2;
    function destroyed(err) {
        // Terminate immediately if there's an error.
        if (err)
            done(err);

        // If there's nothing left to destroy, then call done().
        if (!--to_destroy)
            done();
    }

    dbDestroyCenter('param1','param2')(destroyed);
    dbDestroyCenter('param1','param2')(destroyed);
});
```

This is the general principle.

Comment: This is indeed the general principle behind modules that do this for you, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [step](https://github.com/creationix/step).  So while it's valuable to see a demonstration, I wouldn't recommend re-inventing this wheel!